# .Net System.Text.Json cannot serialize object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, serialization, system.text.json

I can't serialize `BaseResponse<NoContent>` object. But `Device` object serialized successfully. I didnt find reason

```
 var data = new BaseResponse<NoContent>();
 var json1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
 var data2 = new Device();
 var json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data2);
```

`BaseResponse` Content :

```
public class BaseResponse<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        public BaseResponse()
        {
            Data = new T();
        }
        public T Data;

        public string Status = "Success";

        public List<string> Errors;

        public BaseResponse<T> AddError(string message)
        {
            Errors ??= new List<string>();
            Status = "Error";
            Errors.Add(message);
            return this;
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** Newtonsoft.Json can serialize both of them. I decided use Newtonsoft.

Comment: Can you post NoContent class and the object that you can not serialize pls?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add getters and setters

```
public class BaseResponse<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public BaseResponse()
    {
        Data = new T();
    }
    public T Data {get; set;}

    public string Status  {get; set;} = "Success";

    public List<string> Errors {get; set;}

    public BaseResponse<T> AddError(string message)
    {
        Errors ??= new List<string>();
        Status = "Error";
        Errors.Add(message);
        return this;
    }
}
```

test

```
    var data = new BaseResponse<NoContent>();
    data.AddError("error message");
    var json1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

output

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Content": "No Content"
  },
  "Status": "Error",
  "Errors": [
    "error message"
  ]
}
```

NoContent class

```
public class NoContent
{
    public string Content {get; set;} ="No Content";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's missing is the option to include fields, by default `System.Text.Json` does not serialize fields, only properties.

You can change this behaviour by supplying `JsonSerializerOptions`, e.g:

```
var json1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, new JsonSerializerOptions() { IncludeFields = true });
```